# Objects are not retaining original location in animation?

Tags: animation, objects, keyframes

I'm pretty new to animation in blender 2.8, as I have not used Blender for the past year or two. I am working on an animation that involves the text of a logo flying around in the air, rotating and changing position as they move around in the air. At the end of the animation, the texts are supposed to come together and form one cohesive word. So, I placed my objects at their final destination, at frame 120, and set a LocRot keyframe to each individual letter. Then, starting at frame 0, I put the letters in random locations with random rotations and put a LocRot keyframe. To see how it looked, I played the animation, however, when I did, all of the letters just moved to one spot, and clumped up on top of each other. [image: What the 120th frame should look like] [image: The Randomly located and rotated text at frame 0[![Frame 44[![Frame 78[![What the 120th frame actually looks like[![Again, frame 120]][3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kV4NY.png)][4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6bN4B.png)][5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eryvM.png)][6](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A7rkt.png)

Here is a link to the original animation I did when the company had a different logo, and I am basically making this same animation for the new logo.
https://youtu.be/WjcO_cZPI3g
How do I fix this issue?

Comment: May be they all have the same action. Check it out in the Action Edtior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. it was because I changed the origin of the letters after setting the final keyframe. in turn, the objects moved to where their previous origin was instead of their actual location.

Answer (score 0):

A lot of times, animators would make the first keyframe and that position, but when they make the next position and keyframe it, they are still on the same frame. This causes the old keyframes to be overwritten by the new ones. This could be the problem here.